Anyone know who to use the /ui-api/object-info/
The documentation says to use a GET operation to see if an object supports the UI API.  But I don't get how to use that URL.  I've tried some ad-hoc GET REST requests and no URL I try works...
/ui-api/object-info/Account
/services/v58.0/ui-api/object-info/Account
etc.
I'm thinking that some higher level information about how to use the URL is missing.

/services/data/v62.0/ui-api/object-info/Account
This is the correct URL.
